# Attempting to use folder other than /var/www/html

Tags: lamp, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I am running Ubuntu (+LAMP) stack for my webserver. Everything for webserver seems to be working fine. For example I have index.php page with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

inside /var/www/html & also under /var/www/mytestsite.com/
From inside the webserver, both sites @ `http://MyServerIPAddress/hello.php` & `http://MyServerIPAddress/mytestsite.com/hello.php` are working showing proper phpinfo.

When I test the same from outside the server, I can only reach page inside /var/www/html 
`http://MyServerIPAddress/hello.php`
But page access to 
`http://MyServerIPAddress/mytestsite.com/hello.php`
Message shows

```
Not Found
The requested URL /example.com was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at *MyServerIPAddress* Port 80.
```

Here is mytestsite.com.conf I used for apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mytestsite.com
    ServerName mytestsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mytestsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mytestsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And also matched folder access & owner setting to the match for both /var/www/html and /var/www/mytestsite.com

**What extra configuration DO I need to be able to access sites outside /var/www/html folder?**

Comment: What if you try placing index.php at `/var/www/html/mytestsite.com/`?

Comment: that works too. Only if I create a new folder at the same level as /var/www/html I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question after looking at apache logs and help from others
First thing I changed my website's apache conf file to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@mytestsite.com
        ServerName mytestsite.com
        ServerName <ServerIpAddress>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www/mytestsite.com/public_html**/>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I made changes to /etc/hosts file to include include the site as

```
<localhostIp>       localhost
<localhostIp>       ubuntu
<ServerIpAddress>   mytestsite.com mytestsite.com
```

After I made the changes, I can access site from outside the server